# Aurelia-Permission show when two permissions are required

Tags: aurelia

from the documentation at https://www.npmjs.com/package/aurelia-permission I have found out that I can have the following:

```
<div global-permission-show="can: addUsers, deleteUsers">Can add or delete users!</div>
```

But what about if I want this?

```
<div global-permission-show="can: addUsers, deleteUsers">Can add and delete users!</div>
```

Is that not possible with aurelia-permission? In the documentation I do not find anything like it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the docs, the maintainer talks about possible [upcoming improvements](https://www.npmjs.com/package/aurelia-permission#feature-possible-improvements) 
such as roles. A role, that can be a combination of permissions could be a straightforward solution for what you need.

But as of now, you could always create a new permission either in your client-side or backend code such as `canManage` which will only be added to your permissions if
both `addUsers` and `deleteUsers` are available in the list.

```
const userPermissions = ['addUsers', 'deleteUsers', 'someOtherPermission']
const userCanManage = true // check if "userPermissions" contains both "addUsers" and "deleteUsers"
const userPermissionsExtended = [...userPermissions, ...(userCanManage ? ['canManage'] : [])]
```

And then you could setup `aurelia-permission` with `userPermissionsExtended` resulting the possibility to do what you need.

`<div global-permission-show="can: canManage">Can add and delete users!</div>`